# Context leak in Wolfram Script?

Tags: output, scripting

**hello.nb**

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellContext -> Notebook]

Print["hello"];

a = 1;
Print[a];

Print@Context[]
```

**bye.nb**

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellContext -> Notebook]

Print["bye"];

Print[a];

Print@Context[]
```

**Wolfram Script**

```
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript
(* ::Package:: *)

UsingFrontEnd[
  Map[
   NotebookEvaluate@FileNameJoin[{$UserDocumentsDirectory, #}] &,
   {"hello.nb", "bye.nb"}
   ]
  ];

Quit[]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ummm.... what's your question?

Comment: This is a bug or a feature? Perhaps I misunderstand how `UsingFrontEnd` works. Is there a workaround?

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev it seems like they did what you told them to do. Try it in the other order?

Comment: @CATrevillian I am not sure that I fully understand your idea...

Comment: Did you try using `math -script` instead of `wolframscript`? (Just curious if it makes a difference)

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev you request hello.nb then bye.nb. These both print a, however only hello defines it. This, to me, makes sense that then, using (the same[?]) frontend, you would be defining a, then calling it to print in hello.nb, after which you then call a to print in bye.nb, which properly returns what is likely Global’a or, at the very least, is pulling the localized value of a from the frontend being used to run both hello.nb and bye.nb, so logic dictates that trying bye.nb then hello.nb will return undefined a, then 1.

Comment: Can you also insert a line to print the context of the symbol?

Comment: @Szabolcs I added `Print @ Context []`, and in both cases it is `Global`

Comment: @CATrevillian Thanks for the help! But I need to evaluate in this order and not worry about leaks :-) I specifically define `CellContext` for each notebook. But it seems that it's ignored.

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev I don’t have the right experience to provide an adequate answer, but you’re defining them to have the same context, which is Notebook, but this should have isolated them, though I suspect it is related to the use of NotebookEvaluate, I could say you should just wrap them in modules to force them to be local, or just define a context other than both having the general Notebook context. You’ve got the attention of those who know way more than me, though! On a real basic-person(myself) level, it is doing what you told it to do. Perhaps Notebook’a or $CellContext’a would isolate a.

Comment: @Szabolcs I found a workaround. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**WORKAROUND**

`$Context` instead of `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellContext -> Notebook]`

**hello.nb**

```
$Context = "H`"

Print["hello"];

a = 1;
Print[a];

Print@Context[]
```

**bye.nb**

```
$Context = "B`"

Print["bye"];

Print[a];

Print@Context[]
```

[image]

Comment: Hah! I knew at least most of half of what I was talking about, great implementation! Do you have any issue with the printing of the context occurring? Any idea how to eliminate that?

Comment: @CATrevillian Thank you very much! You and @Szabolcs helped me a lot. I was understanding that the problem was in context, but it did not occur to me to see the context, because I thought it was unique. By the way, I reported this problem to the Wolfram Support. I will add the `bugs` tag when they confirm this.